# Linux OpenSuse42.3 - port status

Tags: linux, linux-networking, opensuse

I am redirecting this question from another site as I have a problem, which I hope somebody can point me to the right direction.

**Problem >>>**

A) Our external provider (connects via VPN) needs to access "OpenSuse42.3" to specific ports, which
"nmap" or "ncat" tools shows as "filtered" or "refused".

B) No services are listening on these ports.

C) No firewall is running on this server.

D) Security team opened these ports on firewall with evidence that connection get reset by server
"OpenSuse42.3".

Test runs from "10.10.10.2" to "10.10.10.1" (problem server) from provider VPN connection (from my computer)

**Example 1 : from "10.10.10.2"**

> > > nmap -sT -p1101,3050 10.10.10.1

```
 PORT     STATE    SERVICE
 1101/tcp filtered pt2-discover
 3050/tcp filtered gds_db
```

**Example 2 : from "10.10.10.2"**

> > > nc -z -v 10.10.10.1 1101

```
  Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
  Ncat: Connection refused.
```

> > > nc -z -v 10.10.10.1 3050

```
  Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
  Ncat: Connection refused.
```

**Example 3: on server "10.10.10.1"**

> > > tcpdump -n -i eth0 port 1101 or port 3050 -v

```
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes

13:00:28.940582 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 32383, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60) 
10.10.10.2.58000 > 10.10.10.1.1101: Flags [S], cksum 0xa3fc (correct), seq 3906215335, win 29200, 
options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1388733400 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

13:00:28.940662 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40440, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40) 
10.10.10.1.1101 > 10.10.10.2.58000: Flags [R.], cksum 0x347b (correct), seq 0, ack 3906215336, win 0, 
length 0

13:00:31.263502 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 60627, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60) 
10.10.10.2.40830 > 10.10.10.1.3050: Flags [S], cksum 0x8bc2 (correct), seq 3504308280, win 29200, 
options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1388735723 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

13:00:31.263569 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40888, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40) 
10.10.10.1.3050 > 10.10.10.2.40830: Flags [R.], cksum 0x2554 (correct), seq 0, ack 3504308281, win 0, 
length 0
```

**BUT**

As soon as I put something on the server like - "nc -l 1101" or "nc -l 3050" problem disappears, which  makes sense. To my knowledge "nmap" tool usually shows port status as "closed" if port is not firewalled and service is not running and "open" if service is running on this port.

**Question**

Are ports opened or closed ??? I think that I am correct and ports ARE OPEN. What else do I check, because provider keep insisting that ports are closed on "10.10.10.1" and he cannot continue his work. He uses test as - "telnet 10.10.10.1 1101".

Please let me know if something is unclear in this situation and I will respond.

Appreciate it !!!!

Comment: You can always see if a service is listening on a port by using netstat. For example: netstat -a -n -p -t -l(-a - all users, not just yours, requires root; -n - don't resolve IP addresses to host names; speeds things up; -p - show what process is listening; -t - show TCP connections only, change to -u if your service uses UDP; -l - show listening/open ports only). By the way, telnet will only test TCP connections, it won't work on UDP, but it does work in most cases.

Comment: Also if nc -l 1101 on 10.10.10.1 actually works, it means that whatever service is supposed to be listening on port 1101 is not running. Normally if a port is already in use, you should get something like "nc: Address already in use" from nc, even if you run it as root, although you shouldn't need to, because 1101 > 1024 (i.e. unprivileged port).

Comment: Thank you Rouben!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ports are obviously closed, because no service is listening on them, and they return an RST in response to a SYN. They can't be open, because no service is listening. You even demonstrated this yourself with `nc -l`.

You seem to be confusing open vs. closed (whether a service listens on the port) with allowed vs. denied (whether the port is firewalled). The ports are clearly not firewalled either.

If a service is supposed to be listening on that port, you need to start that service.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. Your answer is clear.